# understanding Continuity in topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, self-learning

Let $(X, \mathscr T_X)$ and $(Y, \mathscr T_Y)$ be topological spaces and $f: X \to Y$. $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1} (E) \in \mathscr T_X $ for every $E \in \mathscr T_Y$.

**My doubt is**:

I dont know if $f$ is bijective so how can I define $f^{-1}(E)$?

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is here not the inverse function but the pre-image map, $f^{-1} \colon \mathfrak{P}(Y) \to \mathfrak{P}(X);\quad f^{-1}(B) = \{ x\in X : f(x) \in B\}$. That is always defined.

Comment: I got your point and my doubt has also been cleared but I didn't understand your notation. What is the meaning of $\mathfrak{P}(Y) \to \mathfrak{P}(X)$ ??

Comment: $\mathfrak{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$, the same for $Y$ of course. $f^{-1}$ is a map from subsets of $Y$ to subsets of $X$.

Comment: But why did you use power set when we are supposed to choose an open set with respect to the given topology i.e. $E \in \mathscr T_Y$?? (Power set is the finest topology, right??  but aren't we suppose to choose (open) set from $\mathscr T_Y$ and $\mathscr T_X$ ?)!!

Comment: The topologies are subsets of the power set, $\mathscr{T}_Y \subset \mathfrak{P}(Y)$. The definition of continuity is that $f^{-1}$ maps elements of the subset $\mathscr{T}_Y$ into the subset $\mathscr{T}_X$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a theorem but the definition of continuity. Second, note that $$f^{-1}(E) := \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in E\}$$

so there is absolutely no requirement of $f$ being injective or even bijective.

Comment: Let $x_1 ,x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \in E$. So if we are taking the pre image of $E$ in $X$ then will we take both these points $x_1$ and $ x_2$ (i.e. in $ f^{-1}(E)$)??

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of preimage.